# TimeStamp on ICMP on Scapy (Python)

Tags: python, timestamp, scapy, icmp

## Context

*(If you are skilled in Scapy you may want to jump this part)*

I was tasked to do some basic ICMP package that "doesn't look like a fake package".
So I started writing some code in Python with Scapy libraries, somewhat like this:

```
import scapy.all as scapy
import scapy.layers.inet as inet
import scapy.fields as fields
import sys
import random
import os
import time


'''some other code...'''

def packbuilder(sec, messagechar):
    packet = inet.IP(src=configured_ips[0], dst=configured_ips[1])
    packet[inet.IP].ttl = 64
    packet[inet.IP].id = os.getpid() & 0xFFFF
    del packet[inet.IP].chksum
    packet = packet/inet.ICMP()
    packet[inet.ICMP].id = icmp_id
    packet[inet.ICMP].seq = sec
    del packet[inet.ICMP].chksum
    timestamp = int(time.time() * 10**9)
    datatime = scapy.struct.pack('<Q', timestamp)
    packet = packet / scapy.Raw(load=datatime + messagechar.encode() + b'\x00')
    return packet
```

## The Issue

As you may all know, ICMP packages in Scapy are made by stacking layers one over the other, and within this layers there are what are called **"fields"**.
A "common" **field** that is in many ICMP packages is indeed **Timestamp**. As you can see, in the code (that I borrowed form a friend of friend), scapy adds datatime to scapy.Raw, which is the last layer of a Package in Scapy (*Don't know if is actually mandatory to have it at last*), and so it adds timestamp... **except it doesn't**

[Actual Package seen in Wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWF2O.png)

So I started loooking in Scapy's library and eventually I found what I was looking for with another problem, which is actually what this whole thing is about:

[scapy.layers.inet.ICMPTimeStamp**Field**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZGW5.png)

[Click here to see the actual reference](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.layers.inet.html)

You may realize that unlike **scapy.layers.inet.ICMP()**, scapy.layers.inet.ICMPTimeStampField() isn't a packet, but a field, so you cannot stack it like you would stack a packet.

I've been reading the [Scapy Fields Simple Datatypes](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_dissect.html#simple-datatypes) but it seems that is for making new kinds of packages, and I don't want to make a new kind of package.
I want to make a ICMP with a timestamp field, using scapy.layers.inet.ICMPTimeStampField() but I don't know how to use it.I might have to make a new kind of package (I know...) but at least that  is for common us in ICMP methods.

```
import scapy.all as scapy
import scapy.layers.inet as inet
import scapy.fields as fields
import sys
import random
import os
import time


'''some other code...'''

def packbuilder(sec, messagechar):
    packet = inet.IP(src=configured_ips[0], dst=configured_ips[1])
    packet[inet.IP].ttl = 64
    packet[inet.IP].id = os.getpid() & 0xFFFF
    del packet[inet.IP].chksum
    packet = packet/inet.ICMP()
    packet[inet.ICMP].id = icmp_id
    packet[inet.ICMP].seq = sec
    del packet[inet.ICMP].chksum
    timestamp = int(time.time() * 10**9)
    datatime = scapy.struct.pack('<Q', timestamp)
    packet = packet / scapy.Raw(load=datatime + messagechar.encode() + b'\x00')
    return packet
```

What i really need is something like this:

[Ideal Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD8Ia.png)